# How can I do to remove the circle?

Tags: javascript, html, django, select, css-selectors

Hello I have this select but I got an error with that :

Here is my code :

```
<label for="id_user">{% 'User' %}
    <select name="user" id="id_user" class="form-control user"
    data-live-search="true" data-width="100%"
    ng-change="user()" ng-init="user()"
    ng-model="user">
    <option value=""></option>
    {% for user in users %}
    <option data-content="{{ user.displayname }}" value="{{ user.uniqueid }}">
    {{ user.displayname }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</label>
```

Actually I got this :

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Cn6.png)

I don't know why I got two circles like this...

Anyone can help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line:

```
<option value=""></option>
```